# Visual Studio WSDL Generation Tool Plugin

Tags: class, proxy, wsdl

I have strange problem which is concerned to Visual Studio 2010 Add-ins. I have installed *WSDL Generation Tools 2010* Add-in to generate proxy classes from WSDL files. The problem is when first time I have opened a Visual in *Tools* tab there was *WSDL generation tool* but when I restore settings there was no longer this add-in. What is strange: when I run Visual there is still window *Wsdl generation info* and in *Add-in manager* there is still checked *Wsdl Generation 2010* option but in *Tools* list there is no this tool.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a link to this tool? I've never heard of it.

Comment: The problem is I can't do it. But I have resolved this problem. I just added this add-in manually by customizing tools :)